# Meshlab :export xyzrgb

Tags: cloud, point, meshlab

I have a point cloud (XYZIRGB) that I opened in Meshlab to tidy up and remove some points.

When I come to export, I only have the option of XYZ. There are additional options, but the only available one is Normals on/off. I've tried with both, but no success in getting colours, as it remains grayed out.

Am I just missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: this is a site to help you with coding problems, not with software related to coding. please show some code and the problem you have with it

Comment: What is the extension of the file? Post first few lines from the file (including one or more vertex data) to show the content of the file.

Comment: weirdly I was directed here for the help.  hoijui. Will look elsewhere.

Comment: Atekihcan - reading the file isn't the issue. It was exporting the file. a simple X,Y,Z,R,G,B. The only export option they have doesn't include RGB values ehich is odd as they import it and display it so the info is in the file

Answer (score 0):

You can export it as a .ply in ascii format (uncheck "binary encoding") and it will give you the option to export colors.  The file will contain some header information though.